# Checking for clicks inside an HTML5 video element

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I am trying to create a webpage with a video, and when the video is clicked on (not just the controls) I can run some JavaScript function. What I would like to be able to do is display subtitles within the video, and when one of the words is clicked, I can display some information below the video depending on the word they clicked on.

I couldn't find anything on the internet that seemed to concern anything similar to this, so thanks in advance if anyone can help.

EDIT: I am now able to get the location of the click (http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/09/02/click-image-and-get-coordinates-with-javascript/), but I need to know how to find the location of the subtitles.

Comment: Just bind click event on video element?

Comment: But with a click event, can I check the location of the click? And if so, how can I find the bounds of a subtitle?

Comment: how are you encoding your subtitles into the video? is it soft coded or hard coded?

Comment: If by that you mean whether or not they are in the video file, then it is not part of the video file. Right now I am using WebVTT, but I am open to using any subtitle format that would work.

Comment: if you are using a webVTT file, then it is nothing but a text file that is going to be rendered at a certain time slot. I am not entirely sure if you can embed hyperlinks into those texts

Comment: I don't need hyperlinks, I just need to find out which word is clicked.

Comment: @farlepet-- BubbleJS:  http://bubbles.childnodes.com/  maybe this would help?

Comment: I have seen that, but those (the top video, with the clickable captions) are more like popups/annotations. I would like subtitles like the ones seen in the lower video, but at the same time being able to click on them (not as a hyperlink)

Comment: finding the location of each word in the subtitles will be difficult - varies by browser exactly how it will render. I'd suggest ingesting the VTT yourself and using javascript to add an onclick to each word and then display it yourself

Comment: I've decided that, at least for now, a box below the video with clickable words would be fine, and maybe in the future I will try to overlay those words on top of the video.